# Countability in natural numbers and real numbers.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let me have the following representation of natural numbers- $n$ will be represented as $\dots 00n$. Now arrange the natural numbers in some sequence $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots\}$.

Say $n=12$. Then index the digits in the following manner- the index of $2$ is $1$, the index of $1$ is $2$, the index of $0$ is $3$, and so on (go on to number the infinite number of zeroes).

We can prove that there is always a natural number not present in any sequence of natural numbers. How? Go to the $i^{th}$ position of $x_i$ for every $i\in \Bbb{N}$, and change the digit present to any other digit. This algorithm is well known. This new natural number is not present in this particular sequence. Similarly, we can prove that every sequence of natural numbers misses out some natural number.

The argument above is obviously fallacious, as arranging the natural numbers in their natural order itself ensures that no number is missed out. However, the argument above is given to prove that $\Bbb{R}$ is not countable. Check out [this](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDYQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.dartmouth.edu%2F~m54x12%2Fm54lecture2.pdf&ei=QCaWUvyvLsSrrAfSqIGwDw&usg=AFQjCNHTe9yp6exSrf-hRyZGzg8qelXbOA&bvm=bv.57155469,d.bmk) link for instance. How is this possible? Am I not understanding the argument?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the $i$'th digit then you will necessarily have infinitely many non-zero digits. No natural number have infinitely many non-zero digits.

---

Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564479/question-about-cantors-diagonal-argument/564492#564492 for a list of Cantor's diagonal related questions. In particular links number 3,4,6 and 9.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is not well-defined. It will create things that are not numbers, but sequences instead.

If you keep changing digits for every natural... you cannot guarantee that you will have a moment that all next digits are 0 (which would "be" a natural number).